# Does Facebook Messenger provides the timezone on the subscribed webhook?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I am creating a Chatbot where i would to like to show timing details in local timezone. Does Facebook Messenger provides the timezone on the subscribed webhook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [the received message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message-received), the timezone isn't specified:

```
{
  ...
  "timestamp":1458692752478,
  ...
}
```

But you can get the timezone of the user using the [user profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile):

```
{
  ...
  "timezone": -7,
  ...
}
```

With that information, you get the real date depending on the user timezone.

Comment: Do you know if this changes automatically based on the timezone the user is in or the default set at the profile level?  I got to thinking if someone sets up a 7am Daily Digest time could they potentially get it at 4am on the opposite coast?

Comment: It uses the default set at the profile level. Your defined timezone on Facebook does change when you travel (as far as I know)

Comment: @j0k but this timezone is not precise, since for instance you can find 2 different timezones having the same value in number(+3 for instance). Doesn't the time change for two timezones which   has different name but same numeric value?